# why the name stable set?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

What is the reason for calling independent sets as stable sets of a graph? Is the stable set says anything more about the graph other than it is just a set of pairwise non adjacent vertices?

Answer (score 4):

"Stable" sets used to be called "internally stable" sets, and the independence number $\alpha(G)$ used to be called the "coefficient of internal stability". Unfortunately, none of the early adopters explain why this makes any sense.

The earliest occurrence of "internally stable" sets that I could find was in Berge's article [Two theorems in graph theory](http://www.pnas.org/content/43/9/842.short) (1957), and later in his 1958 textbook on graph theory. It's possible that in French, there's an obvious connection between "internal stability" and vertices not being adjacent that justifies the terminology.

I can also find some references (e.g., [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167506008703340)) which refer to a dominating set (that is, a set $S$ such that every vertex in $V(G) \setminus S$ has a neighbor in $S$) as an "externally stable" set.